# How can i save the campaign name from responsys on a form

Tags: forms, freemarker, responsys

I'm trying to get the name of the campaign where the person opened the form and save it in the supplemental table of the form.
I saw that it has the campaignname() function but I didn't know how to use it.
the form call in the body of the email:

`$personalizedform('test_form', 'EMAIL_ADDRESS_',concat(CAMPAIGN_NAME=campaignname()))$`

and the hidden field in the form:

`<input type="hidden" name="CAMPAIGN_NAME" value="$CAMPAIGN_NAME$">`

Answer (score 0):

i managed to figure out how to do this and it was really dumb of me not to notice it but i can just use campaign.name in the form call

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the limited information, I'd think that you'd want to write your form input to a supplemental table using the form rules, and have the input name/id match a column in your supplemental table.

The freemarker/RPL code to pass campaign name to a form would look something like this: `${form('test_form','EMAIL_ADDRESS_','CAMPAIGN_NAME='+campaign.name())}`

Sources:

- [Responsys Form Method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-develop/RPL/MethodReference.htm#form)
- [Responsys Namespace Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/responsys-develop/RPL/NamespaceReference.htm#Campaign)